# python - django - using a flag on each model field

Tags: python, django

I want to build a simple moderation system for my application.I have a class in my application models like this:

```
#models.py
class TableName(models.Model):
        is_qualified = False
        title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="DEFAULT VALUE")  
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='somepath')
        picture_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='somepath')
```

I have 3 questions:

1. How can I add `is_qualified` to every field in my model and setting it to `False` as default?
2. How can I write a view method first for checking if admin checked an object (for example title or description) and used its checkbox to change field's `is_qualified` value to `True`?
3. How to add a checkbox for each object in admin area for using that view method?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, adding is_qualified for each field would be a bit too much.

If your are using postgresql I would consider using [django-hstore](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore), where you can dynamically add key-value fields.

Using this package, you can make something like your field name as a key, and True/False as a value.

Then when trying to validate is your object "qualified" you just make something like this:

`is_valid = all([value for key, value in your_hstore_field.items()])`

---

EDIT

```
class TableName(models.Model):
        is_qualified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="DEFAULT VALUE")  
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='somepath')
        picture_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='somepath')
        data = hstore.DictionaryField()
```

Then you can have some custom function like this:

```
def update_qualified(obj_instance):
    if all(value for key, value in obj_instance.data.items()):
        obj_instance.is_qualified = True
    else:
        obj_instance.is_qualified = False
    obj_instance.save()
```

Comment: I'm in local developing environment with sqlite3 but i will use postgresql for deployment. So Can i use is_valid in my view methods? or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, let's say, you have validated all of your fields with True / False value in your hstore field. Either you check it always (which can be time consuming with a lot of objects), or you add new field which is this "main" validation indicator. I've updated my code in an answer, please check how I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `is_qualified` an actual field - a BooleanField would be appropriate - and have it default to False.

```
is_qualified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can also look at documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield)

Comment: this is good. but i want this on every field in this class. isn't this for whole class (whole database record)? Please imagine admin will be allowed to qualify each object that he wants. for example he will accept video and picture and title but he will not accept description.

Comment: Add individual fields `title_is_qualified`, `description_is_qualified` following Daniels example for every field in your class

Comment: thank you very much. I think it will work. can you help me about checkboxes too?